# Powershell Current time minus n seconds in specific format

Tags: powershell, formatting, timestamp

I am looking to store value of **current system time - 30 seconds in the format [yy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss] in a variable.**
This is a specific requirement as the log file i am working on has this format. Currently i have below code which allows me to store current system time in required format but unable to subtract 30 seconds.

```
$dateTime = Get-Date -f "[yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss]"
$("Current time: " + $dateTime)
$("Current time - 30 second: " + $dateTime.AddSeconds(-31))
```

The line `$("Current time - 30 second: " + $dateTime.AddSeconds(-31))` from above code throws below error

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'AddMinutes'.
At C:\Users\foo\log_mont.ps1:4 char:3
+ $("Current time - 30 second: " + $dateTime.AddSeconds(-31))
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Just a thought: Wouldn't it be better to show the seconds in your code and not just the minutes? Otherwise it could happen that you don't even see the difference between current time and current time minus 30 seconds.  ;-)

Comment: Yup... I was just playing with script... Posted code with min instead of sec... I will correct that... Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

`$dateTime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(-31).ToString("[yy.MM.dd HH:mm]")`

Note that  this, and your original example, are not storing the date in this format.  They are creating a string representation of the date.  This is why you can't add seconds to it.  If you want to manipulate the date later in your script, store it as a `DateTime` and only use the formatting when you need to output it.  For example:

```
$dateTime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(-31)

# other code - maybe some date manipulation

$dateTime.ToString("[yy.MM.dd HH:mm]")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have (direct) control over the the date time to subtract 30 seconds from you can use `[datetime]::ParseExact()` to convert the ***string*** to a `[datetime]` type you can subtract from and convert to string again.
(What only makes sense including seconds, what you did in your last edit)

```
$dtformat = "\[yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss\]"
$dateTime = Get-Date -f $dtformat
$dateTime
[datetime]::ParseExact($datetime,$dtformat,$Null).AddSeconds(-30).ToString($dtformat)
```

Sample output:

```
[18.07.16 14:49:22]
[18.07.16 14:48:52]
```